# Ember doesn't recognize model data in subfolder

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

The following structure of routes works fine for me.

[image: Correct Structure]

But whenever I moved faculty.js inside the faculty folder, my template stops recognizing the data. The static view elements still show up correctly, but the data model is logged as null. How can I fix it?

[image]

faculty.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
      return {name:"Janusz", lastname:"Chudzynski", department:"Test"};
  }
});
```

faculty.hbs

```
{{outlet}}
<h2>Faculty</h2>
{{log  model}}
{{faculty-single  facultyModel=model}}
```

Router

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('colleges');
  this.route('departments');
   this.route('faculty',{path:'/faculty'});
  //this.route('faculty');
});
```

export default Router;

Console log

> null

Comment: Can you include your router? The file structure should be the same as your router.

Comment: I just added it. So the h2 is rendered correctly, but the model is logged as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hierarchy of your folders should closely mirror the hierarchy of your router. In your case you have the following:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('colleges');
  this.route('departments');
  this.route('faculty');
});
```

This means that all of them are directly under the `application` route, being the correct file structure:

```
app
  routes
    colleges.js
    departments.js
    faculty.js
```

For `/app/routes/faculty/faculty.js` to work, you would need to have a `faculty` route nested inside a `faculty` route:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('colleges');
  this.route('departments');
  this.route('faculty', function() {
    this.route('faculty');
  });
});
```

Since names concatenate, the parent route's full name is `faculty`, and the nested route's full name is `faculty.faculty`.

Comment: I would add that if you're visiting `/faculty` and expecting to see this route, you can keep the directory structure and rename this file `index.js`

Comment: In this case what's the role of the path parameter?  I was expecting it would solve this problem. 

this.route('faculty',{path:'/faculty'});

Comment: The path is how it will show up in the URL bar, not in the file system.